# Get the hour right in Swift

Tags: string, date, formatter

Im trying with a String to Date formatter but have been getting it wrong.
Calling the function like this:

```
self.stringToDate(date: "26 10 1995 10:54:00")
```

This is the Function:

```
func stringToDate(date: String) -> Date {
        print(date)
        let formatter4 = DateFormatter()
        formatter4.dateFormat = "dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss"
        return formatter4.date(from: date)!
    }
```

And this is the result in console:

```
26 10 1995 10:54:00
1995-10-26 16:54:00 +0000
```

Comment: check your time zone.

Comment: As far I know there is nothing to change with the time zone, look no further https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33639037/swift-get-correct-time-zone-from-date-picker

Comment: see DateFormater.timeZone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check

```
import Foundation

let form = DateFormatter()
form.dateFormat = "dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss"
print(form.timeZone, form.date(from: "26 10 1995 10:54:00") ?? "")

form.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
print(form.timeZone, form.date(from: "26 10 1995 10:54:00") ?? "")

form.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EST")
print(form.timeZone, form.date(from: "26 10 1995 10:54:00") ?? "")
```

it prints

```
Optional(Europe/Bratislava (current)) 1995-10-26 09:54:00 +0000
Optional(GMT (fixed)) 1995-10-26 10:54:00 +0000
Optional(America/New_York (fixed)) 1995-10-26 14:54:00 +0000
```